# How to convert innerHTML into an array where I can use .size() function. etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, innerhtml

I would like to put an innerHTML I got into an array, from there I can access its size and each character in it. (Each character takes 1 slot in the array).

For example

```
<script type=text/javascript>

var tester=document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML;

//testerArray = conversion function goes here? <<<<<


alert (testerArray.size());
alert (testerArray[2]);

</script>
```

Help is appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testerArray = [].slice.call( tester );`

there is no `.size()` for arrays though and you could already use `.length` for the string. If you actually need array functions, then this is ok

Comment: I remember i used .size() for arrays I obtained using Jquery, is .size() a Jquery function for arrays then?

Comment: Actually I used .size() and it returned me the correct number... confused... maybe because I imported Jquery.js?

Comment: @eastboundr, some other script must have defined it, normally it doesn't exist.

Comment: @ Esailija Ok, as long as it works, it's good for the time being. I will look into it later. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`.length` already does this for strings.

Comment: thanks, yeah that works as well. However I kind want utilize more array functions in the future perhaps...

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
var tester=document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML;

alert(tester.length);
alert(tester.charAt(2));
```

Comment: thanks for the help, this should work too although I kind want to use more array functions in the future to further manipulate it in complex ways...

Comment: then find a use case where using arrays is appropriate.  Don't use arrays just because you want to play with them.  Get into the habit of using the right tool for the job.